# Square Web API for Android

Tags: javascript, android, square

I'm trying to program a button in my web app that will launch the Square app on an Android tablet for payment processing.

I've been following the web developer's guide and I get a syntax error when defining the payment typeType variable: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

[image]

I'm not sure what could be wrong as this is straight from the example on square's documentation.

Can anyone shed some light? Here is a sample of my code.

**Button that launched the javascript code:**

```
<div id="do_square_payment" align="center" style="display:none;">
                                <button id="do_square_payment_btn_android" value="Square" style="background-image:url(images/Square.png); height:200px; width:200px;" onClick="openURL();"></button><br>
</div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script>


                                function openURL(){
                                var amount = document.form.payment_amount_mobile.value;


                                var amountFixed = amount * 100;
                                console.log("Payment amount" + amountFixed);


                                  var posUrl =
                                    "intent:#Intent;" +
                                    "action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;" +
                                    "package=com.squareup;" +
                                    "S.browser_fallback_url=https://jaydien.ezservicetrax.com;" +
                                    "S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=https://jaydien.ezservicetrax.com;" +
                                    "S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=sq0idp-OMMITED;" +
                                    "S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;" +
                                    "S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;" +
                                    "S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CASH;" +
                                    "i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT="  + 
                                    amountFixed +
                                    ";" +
                                    "end";

                                  window.open(posUrl);
                                }
                               </script>
```

Here is the url that is requested when I emulate an android device using the chrome developer tools:

```
intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=https://jaydien.ezservicetrax.com;S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=OMMITED;S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=5.00;S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CASH,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_OTHER;end
```

Comment: Hmm, I think that's simply invalid Javascript (for multiline string), if I'm not mistaken. Could you try using back tick (`) instead of double quotes (") at the beginning and end of the string for `tenderTypes`? Let me know if that works and I can make sure it gets changed in Square's docs.

Comment: Well it doesn't throw that syntax error on an android device anymore, but it crashes the chrome browser when I try to use the link to launch the Square app. Is there any way to see what is going wrong when I click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just some sort of typo in the documentation.

You're trying to create a string literal over mutiple lines and for that you should use the same approach as the `posUrl` variable you instantiate right after the `tenderTypes` one, i.e. closing the quotes and concatenating with the next line using the `+` operator. There are other ways to create a multiline string, like adding `\` at the end of each line so the parser knows that the literal is not finished yet.

Your code would look like this:

```
var tenderTypes =
   "com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD,\
    com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,\
    com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CASH,\
    com.squareup.pos.TENDER_OTHER";
```

or this:

```
var tenderTypes =
   "com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD," +
   "com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE," +
   "com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CASH," +
   "com.squareup.pos.TENDER_OTHER";
```

Comment: Ah... Didin't even notice that those two were different like that. I updated the code to use the + operator and it no longer throws the syntax error. Prob is just a typo in the documentation. Going to test it out on an android device to be sure. I was testing it prior using google chrome with the device emulator.

Comment: "i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=" + transactionTotal + ";" + In my code was the issue. Posted the working code.